# Button and TextViews not same size even though dimensions are identical

Tags: java, android

I want a 2x2 GridLayout of 4 TextViews like so:

```
TV1  TV2
TV3  TV4
```

Then I want 3 Buttons on top of 3 of the TextViews so that when the layout is completed being drawn, this is what the user should see:

```
B1   B2
TV3  B3
```

Note that all the TextViews and Buttons are squares of the same dimensions.  Then the user will be able to slide the Buttons around until the desired pattern is achieved.  So if the user slides B3 to the left, this is what the user will see:

```
B1   B2
B3   TV4
```

But, when my layout is done being drawn, this is what is shown to the user:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
public TextView[] getTList(int level) {
    int iLength = 4;

    TextView[] textviewList = new TextView[iLength];

    for(int i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {
        TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textview.setId(i + 1);
        textviewList[i] = textview;
        textview.setHeight(buttonDimension);
        textview.setWidth(buttonDimension);
        textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        textview.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
    }

    return textviewList;
}

public Button[] getBList(int level) {
    int iLength = 3;

    Button[] buttonList = new Button[iLength];

    for(int i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {
        Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        button.setId(i + 1);
        button.setText(Integer.toString(i + 1));
        setButton(button);
        buttonList[i] = button;
        button.setHeight(buttonDimension);
        button.setWidth(buttonDimension);
        button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

public void level1() {

    tList = getTList(level);
    bList = getBList(level);

    gameplayGL.setColumnCount(2);
    gameplayGL.setRowCount(2);

    Spec r1 = GridLayout.spec(0);
    Spec r2 = GridLayout.spec(1);
    Spec c1 = GridLayout.spec(0);
    Spec c2 = GridLayout.spec(1);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams t1 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r1, c1);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams t2 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r1, c2);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams t3 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r2, c1);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams t4 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r2, c2);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams b1 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r1, c1);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams b2 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r1, c2);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams b3 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r2, c2);

    gameplayGL.addView(tList[0], t1);
    gameplayGL.addView(tList[1], t2);
    gameplayGL.addView(tList[2], t3);
    gameplayGL.addView(tList[3], t4);

    gameplayGL.addView(bList[0], b1);
    gameplayGL.addView(bList[1], b2);
    gameplayGL.addView(bList[2], b3);
}
```

Notice that the Buttons are not squares but instead rectangles.  Also, TV3 appears to be the correct dimensions and the "square" dimensions I want.  Why are the buttons misshaped?  Also, TV1, TV2 and TV4 should be flush up against TV3 but I don't even see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `setPadding(0)` on all controls. If that doesn't work try using `ImageButton` or even just a plain old `ImageView` instead of a button. Also, what is `buttonDimension`? I assume it is `match_parent`, if not try that.

Comment: I will try the `setPadding(0)` method and also the `ImageButton/ImageView` method and report back.  `buttonDimension` is a int that is calculated from the user's screen dimensions.

Comment: Both of your mentioned methods didn't work.  But, it gave me an idea to just make both of the arrays to just be arrays of TextViews instead of having one an array of Buttons.  Works perfectly now.  Thanks for the idea @grennis!